# Delete Multiple Checkbox with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm trying to add the ability to delete a mysql table row by selecting a checkbox and hitting the submit button. Can't figure out what went wrong here and hoping someone can help me out...

Update: the below is now working, though does not use prepared statements as recommended below (still need to learn how to do that).

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Delete </th>
        <th> Column 1 </th>
        <th> Column 2 </th>
        <th> Column  3 </th>
        <th> Form URL </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
        include('connect.php');
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM campaigns ORDER BY ID ASC");
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
    <tr class="record">
    <form method="post">
        <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['camp']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['value']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="editform.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"> edit </a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete Campaign"></td>
    </form>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){

$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM campaigns WHERE ID=$del_id";
$result=$db->query($sql);
}
// if successful redirect 
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
}
 }

?>
```

Comment: What is the error? Do you get any error messages? Are your rows not deleted? What is the situation? Whre is your HTML `form` element? How do you send that data?

Comment: There are no form tags here; your submit button has nothing to submit.

Comment: is this complete code? where is form?

Comment: Rookie mistake! I added the `form` code. Getting error `Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting says it all.

The first parameter of `mysqli_query` is the resource for the connection. The second is the query. I assume that somewhere above the form is the PHP code to actually connect to the MySQL server?

Check the manual pages for `mysqli_query`

----Ignore that----

Actually, it would appear that you're trying to use the object way at the start of the code and then function way lower.

Change your `DELETE...` query to use prepared statements so that your data is sanitised. After that, execute the query and check for errors. If your table is transaction based, wrap your query in a transaction and check for errors so that you can roll back if needs be.

To sum up:

- Choose one method or another to handle your `mysqli` functions.
- Always use prepared statements
- Use transactions where required
- Read the error messages that you get

Comment: Thanks for the tip... got a lot to learn! Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're still using the `mysqli_query` function wrong. You should be using something like `$result=$db->query($sql);` as, I'm assuming, the  connect.php file creates a new `mysqli` object. Look at the query directly below `include('connect.php');` as an example

Comment: Thanks DaveyBoy, I made that change and now not getting an error message. Still not deleting the row, but guess need to figure out how to use prepared statements as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID='$del_id'
```

is your ID field a string value? if not, probably removing the '' will fix it.
Also you could just do

```
foreach($checkbox as $del_id => $value)
```

instead of

```
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){

$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in form tag

```
<form method="post"></form>
```

Tip : Arrange your code , get PHP code outside

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: The `mysqli` connection is defined as an object rather than a resource. This will not work

Comment: or you could try using mysql_connect, mysql_query

Comment: Aamir - bad idea. The `mysql` function set has been deprecated andm as such, should not be used. The fact that OP has attempted to use `mysqli` means that the code is future-proof for a while at least. I think OP is fairly new to PHP and MySQL so telling him to revert to an un-supported feature is not good for his ongoing development

Comment: i just gave a quick fix to him but i agree that mysqli can prove to be future proof... so he shud go with prepared stmts as u said...
P.S - mysql will be supported by future PHP versions, atleast for a while right ??

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yep, I'm pretty new at this and eager to figure it out :)

Comment: Aamir - the `mysql` functions will be present for a while but who knows how long that will be. I'm in the same boat - most of the code I look after is legacy and littered with `mysql_` statements so it's going to take quite a while for me to sort out my systems. Wish me luck